# How to get the memory adresses from a string?

Tags: c++, string, for-loop, memory, iterator

I have a very basic question but i just cant get my head around it.
I wondered how i can retrieve the memory adresses of each charachter in a string.

For example:

```
    string str("Test");
    cout << size(str) << endl;
```

I know this returns this 4 because this string is 4 bytes but how can i output the memory adresses of each byte on the screen?

I did try this

```
string s = "abcd";
string::iterator pos;

for (pos = s.begin(); pos != s.end(); ++pos) {
      cout << &pos << endl;
}

cin.get();
return 0;
```

But this is the output :

```
00AFFB8C
00AFFB8C
00AFFB8C
00AFFB8C
```

But doesnt it needs to be someting like :

```
00AFFB8C
00AFFB8D
00AFFB8E
00AFFB8F
```

So does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: You see the same address because they are stored at same place.

Comment: Oh, so wrong.  The `size(str)` returns the size of the `std::string` object, not the size of text within the `std::string`.  Try `std::string::length()` to get the length of the string.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews - `std::size(c)` returns `c.size()`. You seem to be thinking of `sizeof`.

Comment: &pos is the address of the iterator, which was declared on the stack. ++pos, doesn't increment its address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your loop to:

```
for (pos = s.begin(); pos != s.end(); ++pos) {
      cout << static_cast<void*>( &*pos ) << endl;
}
```

`static_cast` is necessary because `&*pos` has type `char *` which would be printed by `std::ostream` not the way you want.

Answer (score 2):

So many things wrong.

<s>As I stated in my comment, `sizeof(str)` is returning the size of the `std::string` object, not the text inside the object.  The `std::string` object can be any length (not including the text, which may be stored outside of the object).</s>

The `std::string::iterator` is an iterator object.  You are continuously printing the address or location of the **iterator**, not the contents that the iterator points to.

If you want the location of the text in the `std::string` object, look up the `std::string::data()` method.

Comment: The code isn't using `sizeof`; it's using `std::size(str)`, which returns `str.size()`.

Comment: @PeteBecker: When was `std::size` introduced? (thanks)

Comment: @ThomasMatthews C++17.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews - next year. <g>

Answer (score 1):

You see the same address, because you are printing the address of the *iterator*, not of the characters.

Change your code to this:

```
for (pos = s.begin(); pos != s.end(); ++pos) {
      cout << static_cast<void*>(&(*pos)) << endl;
}
```

which will give different addresses, on my machine for example:

```
0x7fff5a7a09cf
0x7fff5a7a09d0
0x7fff5a7a09d1
0x7fff5a7a09d2
```

Comment: -1 The characters are not stored in the same address.  If the characters were stored at the same address, you would only see the last one.

Comment: The address of the iterator is not changing.  The OP is printing the address of the iterator, which doesn't change; the contents of the iterator are what's changing.

Comment: Yeah I found out while I you were posting the answer...Now it seems like I copied you @ThomasMatthews and I have -2, so I guess I Should delete it...But +1 to you for finding it too! :)